# Is Where on an Array (of a struct type) optimized to avoid needless copying of struct values?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, linq

For memory performance reasons I have an array of structures since the number of items is large and the items get tossed regularly and hence thrashing the GC heap. This is not a question of whether I should use large structures; I have already determined GC trashing is causing performance problems. My question is when I need to process this array of structures, should I avoid using LINQ? Since the structure is not small it is not wise to pass it around by value, and I have no idea if the LINQ code generator is smart enough to do this or not. The structure looks like this:

```
public struct ManufacturerValue
{
    public int ManufacturerID;
    public string Name;
    public string CustomSlug;
    public string Title;
    public string Description;
    public string Image;
    public string SearchFilters;
    public int TopZoneProduction;
    public int TopZoneTesting;
    public int ActiveProducts;
}
```

So let's say we have an array of these values and I want to extract a dictionary of custom slugs to manufacturers ID's. Before I changed this to a structure it was a class, so the original code was written with a simple LINQ query:

```
ManufacturerValue[] = GetManufacturerValues();
var dict = values.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.CustomSlug))
                 .ToDictionary(p => p.CustomSlug, p => p.ManufacturerID);
```

My concern is I want to understand how LINQ is going to generate the actual code to build this dictionary. My suspicion is that internally the LINQ code is going to end up something like this naive implementation:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
    var value = values[i];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.CustomSlug)) {
        dict.Add(value.CustomSlug, value.ManufacturerID);
    }
}
```

which would be bad, because the third line is going to create a local copy of the structure, which will be slow because the structure is large and will instead thrash the memory bus. We also do not need anything but the ID and custom slug from it so it will copy a lot of useless information on every iteration. Rather if I coded it efficiently myself, I would write it like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[i].CustomSlug)) {
        dict.Add(values[i].CustomSlug, values[i].ManufacturerID);
    }
}
```

So does anyone know if the code generator is smart enough to use simple array indexing like the second example when generator code to run over arrays of structures, or will it implement the more naive but slower first implementation?

What is the best way to decompile this kind of code to find out what the code generator would actually do for this?

**UPDATE**

These changes are now in production. As it turns out in the process of re-writing the code and using the Dot Memory profiler to identify how much memory was being used and where, I found two memory leaks in the Phalanger PHP compiler code. That was one of the reasons the amount of memory our processes were using kept growing, and one of the memory leaks was really nasty and actually caused by the Microsoft Async code (probably worth a blog or a stack overflow question/answer to help others avoid it).

Anyway, once I found the memory leaks and fixed them I pushed that code live without any of the memory optimizations to convert from classes to structures, and oddly enough this actually caused the GC to thrash even more. I was seeing periods of time when the GC would be using up to 27% of the CPU according to the performance counters. Most likely these big blocks were previously not getting GC'ed due to the memory leaks, so they simply hung around. Once the code was fixed the GC started behaving even worse than before.

Finally we finished up the code to convert these classes to structures using the feedback in this question, and now our total memory usage at peak is about 50% of what it was, it rapidly drops down when the load on the server goes away and more importantly we are seeing only 0.05% of the CPU being used for GC, if even that. So if anyone is wondering whether these changes can have an impact on the real world, they really can, especially if you have objects that normally hang around for a while so get stuck in the 2nd gen heap and then need to get tossed and garbage collected.

Comment: While I think such is an interesting question (when focused around 'struct overhead', anyway), it's usually beneficial to gather some performance data for the actual real-world usage. The observed performance characteristic can help refine the question and, in many cases such perceived overhead is simply not relevant (or not worth fretting about) in a larger program context.

Comment: what about compiling the expression to create the dictionary ? I think it would be efficient.. I don't know too much about it to write an example, but I think it could help you

Comment: Take a look at [WhereArrayIterator](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,4158286b17727025). The `MoveNext` method of this class contains this line: `TSource item = source[index];`. I think this means that such assignment will cause the system to copy the content of the struct that you have.

Comment: You are correct. Looking at the source I am pretty sure it is going to implement the naive approach here.

Comment: You can use a proxy pattern to have light weight proxy classes in front of the heavy weight structs.

Comment: @user2864740 I have already seen performance overheads in the GC code which is why I am doing the memory optimizations, but I figure while I am re-writing the code to use structs I may as well make it as efficient as possible at the same time :)

Comment: @Amit all this would be a whole lot simpler if the C# language had the ability to create a reference pointer to a struct, like we can do in C++. But then again that probably wreaks havoc on the GC. Trade offs...

Comment: In case it isn't clear to you, in terms of performance, a LINQ query will _never_ perform as well as one using raw loops. Except for very special cases, the LINQ to objects implementations are all based off of enumerators which has its own overheads.

Comment: @KendallBennett, I think that the best way to go about this is to do some measurements. Maybe .NET does some optimizations under the hood in case of LINQ.

Comment: The struct is only 40-80 bytes in size. Does the extra copy even result in it being moved 'off stack' (eg. increase GC pressure)?

Comment: @user2864740 no it would be entirely on stack. I am not worried about any GC pressure caused by this, but simply increased memory bus overhead with all the data copying. This is the first struct I am re-writing. I have another one that is about 4x the size and has way more values floating around so I wanted to get it right on this one first. And posting that one would have added a lot of code to the question :)

Comment: @JeffMercado - You say, "the LINQ to objects implementations are all based off of enumerators", but that's not quite right as many of the LINQ operators will recognize if the source implements `ICollection<T>` and directly use the methods there. There are a number of cases where the speed of LINQ will be much faster than raw loops.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Right, that's just one of those special cases.

Comment: @KendallBennett - I'm not sure that you're getting the benefit you think you are by using a `struct`. I thought that allocating arrays of structs still put them on the GC heap, so from a GC point of view using a class would be far better than structs if they are in an array.

Comment: @Enigmativity Oh yes, it makes a huge difference when you have long running objects that make it into the 2nd level heap and then need to be tossed. If you have an array of a million classes, you have a million references that the GC has to track and dispose of. If you have a million structs in an array, you have exactly one reference the GC needs to track. https://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/28/in-managed-code-we-trust-our-recent-battles-with-the-net-garbage-collector

Comment: @kendall note that strict in question mostly contains reference types - there is good chance difference between class and struct in this particular case would not be noticeable.

Comment: @KendallBennett - Ah, if I understand it, an array of `n` structs is treated as a single blob of memory, so `1` reference, but an array of `n` classes is `n + 1` references. So the trade of becomes if the structs are copied willy nilly you have the memory copy hit, but with classes it's just the reference. This sounds like it could go either way to me, depending on the size of the data and the operations performed. Sounds like a race between two horses that needs to timed.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sam Saffron explained it performance tuning the Stack Overflow site. He explains how they ran into similar issues with GC thrashing going on when stuff has to be garbage collected. Sometimes you simply have to move to a more optimized memory structure and it will both use a whole lot less actual memory, and make the collection of the items much faster when you dispose of them. Right now the memory usage on our site is higher than I want, and we are getting GC thrashing showing up in the performance counters. Believe me, I would much prefer to write my code using classes :)

Comment: @Enigmativity of course it is worth pointing out that I have not yet profiled the result of the changes, so I won't know if it actually helps my specific issues until I test it. But I want to make sure I don't introduce other performance issues along the way due to the use of structs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the best way to decompile this kind of code to find out what the code generator would actually do for this?

There is no need to decompile the code. All LINQ to Objects method implementation can be seen at [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3).

Regarding your concrete question. You can expect a lot of `struct` copy operations when using LINQ (and in general `IEnumerable<T>` and `Func<T, ..>` based methods).

For instance, the current element of `IEnumerator<T>` is accessed via property `Current` defined as follows

```
T Current { get; }
```

so accessing at least involves one copy. But enumerator implementations usually store the current element into a field during the `MoveNext` method, so I would say you can safely count 2 copy operations.

And of course, every `Func<T, ...>` will cause another copy because `T` is input argument.

So in general you should avoid LINQ in such scenarios.

Or, you can use the old school technique of simulating reference via array and index. So instead of this:

```
var dict = values
    .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.CustomSlug))
    .ToDictionary(p => p.CustomSlug, p => p.ManufacturerID);
```

you can avoid `struct` copy by using this:

```
var dict = Enumerable.Range(0, values.Length)
    .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[i].CustomSlug))
    .ToDictionary(i => values[i].CustomSlug, i => values[i].ManufacturerID);
```

**UPDATE:** Since seems like there is an interest to the subject, I'll provide you a variation of the last technique which can make your life easier still avoiding the excessive `struct` copy.

Let say your `ManufacturerValue` was a class and you have used a lot of LINQ queries like the one in the example. Then you switched to a `struct`.

You can also create a wrapper `struct` and helper extension method like this

```
public struct ManufacturerValue
{
    public int ManufacturerID;
    public string Name;
    public string CustomSlug;
    public string Title;
    public string Description;
    public string Image;
    public string SearchFilters;
    public int TopZoneProduction;
    public int TopZoneTesting;
    public int ActiveProducts;
}

public struct ManufacturerValueRef
{
    public readonly ManufacturerValue[] Source;
    public readonly int Index;
    public ManufacturerValueRef(ManufacturerValue[] source, int index) { Source = source; Index = index; }
    public int ManufacturerID => Source[Index].ManufacturerID;
    public string Name => Source[Index].Name;
    public string CustomSlug => Source[Index].CustomSlug;
    public string Title => Source[Index].Title;
    public string Description => Source[Index].Description;
    public string Image => Source[Index].Image;
    public string SearchFilters => Source[Index].SearchFilters;
    public int TopZoneProduction => Source[Index].TopZoneProduction;
    public int TopZoneTesting => Source[Index].TopZoneTesting;
    public int ActiveProducts => Source[Index].ActiveProducts;
}

public static partial class Utils
{
    public static IEnumerable<ManufacturerValueRef> AsRef(this ManufacturerValue[] values)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            yield return new ManufacturerValueRef(values, i);
    }
}
```

It's additional (one time) effort, but with the following benefits:

(1) It's a `struct`, but with a fixed size, so the copy overhead will be negligible compared to normal reference (one additional `int`).
(2) You can extend the actual data `struct` size w/o worry.
(3) All you need to do with your LINQ queries is to add `.AsRef()`

Sample:

```
var dict = values.AsRef()
    .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.CustomSlug))
    .ToDictionary(p => p.CustomSlug, p => p.ManufacturerID);
```

Comment: The value ref pattern is really neat. I like that. I was thinking about something similar and this makes sense. What is the reason the ValueRef is a struct also and not a class? I guess it only has two actual values in it (reference and index), so it does make sense to make it a struct also as copying it around will be very cheap.

Comment: I have never seen the public int ManufacturerID => Source[Index].ManufacturerID; syntax before. Is that some kind of Lambda to represent a getter (ahh, I see C# 6)? What is the difference at compile time between the two? I am secretly hoping it might mean the function would be inlined, but I doubt it :)

Comment: It's a C#6 **compiler** feature called *Expression bodied members* and is just a sugar for defining properties/methods. It's exactly the same as `public int ManufacturerID { get { return Source[Index].ManufacturerID; } }` Not lambda at all. And no magic :)

Answer (score 4):

Structs are [pass by value][1] - so I'm fairly certain just the act of using delegates for your `ToDictionary` will result in two copies, regardless of what else is going on.

In other words, consider

```
.ToDictionary(p => p.CustomSlug, p => p.ManufacturerID);
```

As equivalent to:

```
var key = GetKey(values[i]);
var value = GetValue(values[i]);

.ToDictionary(key, value);
```

which obviously creates two copies of the struct to pass to `GetKey` and `GetValue`.

Comment: Interesting. That would actually make it worse than my naive example when using LINQ. I think the answer is to avoid LINQ if you are doing arrays of large structs. Thanks!

Comment: @KendallBennett - well...I'd hesitate to say if and how much difference either your naive and not-naive or LINQ case would actually make in performance; a lot of optimizations can happen in JIT....no substitute for measuring and/or viewing the JITted code....

Comment: Yeah sure, but if the struct contains a lot of data, then the performance difference will be measurable.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to relax the garbage collector a bit, you may want to use [gcServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms229357(v=vs.110).aspx) option in your app.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <gcServer enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

To see what kind of IL is generated based on your LINQ code, [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) is a great tool.

Unfortunately, I dont have any clue about using LINQ against enumeration of structs. I am usually using structs to keep a little amount of value type.

Maybe relaxing the GC will help you to circumvent your performance issue, and give classes another chance ? I also have an application that do a massive amount of object creation and disposal where the performances were plagged by the GC Frenzy. Using GCServer="true" solved it, in exchange of a sligh increase of used private memory.

Comment: This code runs in a web server so it is already using the server GC option. We are noticing after our site has been running for a while we memory usage goes up and CPU usage goes up (almost double). Seems we are routinely seeing 6-8% of CPU used in the GC, and it gets worse the longer the site runs.

Comment: "This code runs in a web server so it is already using the server GC option"  :  I am afraid that GCServer is not enabled by default in server's machine.config. By the sake of curiosity, is this entry actually present in machine.config or yourapp.config files ?

Answer (score 0):

The arrows:

```
p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.CustomSlug)
p => p.CustomSlug
p => p.ManufacturerID
```

are each compiled into an actual method where `p` is a value parameter of the method. Those methods are then passed to Linq in the form of Func delegate instances. Since they are value parameters, your struct is passed by value.

Maybe you can use:

```
ManufacturerValue[] values = GetManufacturerValues();
var dict = Enumerate.Range(0, values.Length)
  .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[i].CustomSlug))
  .ToDictionary(i => values[i].CustomSlug, i => values[i].ManufacturerID);
```

This just captures the array reference in each of the lambda arrows (closures).

Edit: I had not seen that Ivan Stoev's answer already had this suggestion. Upvote his answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have benchmarked the performance of Linq's Where() on 10 million structs vs classes large and small.

Structs are faster in all cases.

code: https://github.com/Erikvv/linq-large-struct-benchmark